# ExpressionEngine add-on question regarding email and social media notification

Tags: add-on, notification, social

I have seen functionality on a Wordpress site that allowed visitors to sign up for notification whenever new content is added to the site. The subscription allowed the user to receive notification of all new additions or to limit notifications to specific categories.

The user could also select how they want to be notified (by email, Facebook, twitter, other social media, etc.).

Does anyone know of an existing EE add-on that can replicate this functionality?

Thanks for your help,

Darin Parker

Answer (score 1):

This is not available OOB or with current addons, but these two addons come the closest to what you need minus the social media integration: [update message](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/update-message) and [Entry Mailing](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-mailing)

You might consider talking to those developers and see if they would be able to add that functionality in - I would imagine that you would need to pay for this extra functionality but it's definitely worth asking.